# Is it not possible to have multiple objects in Qt being painted simultaneously?

Tags: c++, qt, paint

- I read the following in the Qt Documentation.

[Qt documentation on QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#begin)

[The original question on SO, that I looked into.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719494/using-qpainter-with-qpaintdevice-multiple-times)

- So, I had two classes, with their own paint() functions. The paint functions would be called upon receiving their respective paint events, that were triggered on different and independent actions by the user. This worked fine.

  - Now for some reason, I need to show and update both the objects at the same time.
  - So simply, adding both of the items to the scene does not work. Only one of them is shown and updated. Refactoring the code is not an issue for me. I can re-arrange the two classes so that they are both drawn from one paint().

But this really makes me wonder then, and this is my question (for which I've googled a bit too), how are scenes with many dozens of objects then painted simultaneously (at least they give an illusion of concurrency)? Using threads somehow or through some time-based interleaving?

Maybe it's a silly question. I dunno.

Comment: Why would you need to show and update them both at the same time? Why would doing one right after the other not be sufficient? Unless your painting code is pathologically slow, no one would be able to tell the difference.

Comment: If you add them both to the scene they should both be painted. But this should happen automatically if you add them to the scene one after another. In the end, all code is executed one after another as long as it is running in the same thread.

Comment: Well, one of the objects is visible over a long period of time, e.g. a grid and cross lines. The paint call for this first object, effectively blocks the paint call for the other object, which is supposed to draw some QGraphicsItem.

It seems to me, the only fix would be to have one paint() handle all the drawing.

2 different objects with their own paint() functions will not work.
Is that not what the documentation link also says?

Running through with a debugger through the code, I see that the paint() function from the first object is called repeatedly, blocking a call to repaint the other.

Comment: Just to clarify -> The grid and crosslines are updated, as the mouse is moved, giving the coordinate information of the cursor. Therefore they are updated continuously, and hence continuously repainted.

Had they been static, the paint event for them would not have been called.

And only the paint event for the other class that draws a QGraphicsItem, would've been called.

Hence, my original question.

Comment: `void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *) `

Each paint function, in the two classes has a painter. And as the documentation states, there can be only one painter at any given time for one painting device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re `QWidget` painting: The paint events are delivered to individual widgets by the widget compositor. The way it works with the default raster back end is as follows: The topmost widget in the hierarchy is backed by a `QImage`. When any of the sub-widgets are to be repainted, the compositor delivers composite paint events to the widgets that overlay the area to be repainted. This is done *sequentially* as the compositor traverses the widget graph.

Re `QGraphicsItem` painting: The paint "events" are delivered to individual items by the scene. The items to be painted are selected basing on what area needs updating, what items were explicitly marked for update, etc. The painter is set up to correctly composite the item with the rest of the scene. The calls to `paint` are done sequentially as the scene traverses the item graph.

It would be, in general, impossible to do these in *parallel* due to data dependencies, and the fact that there are no requirements for the `paintEvent` or `paint` to be thread-safe.

Your problem is not directly related to this at all, you need to show a complete code example that reproduces your issue. Most likely your implementation of the item ignores some of the requirements for the item's behavior.

Comment: Yes! You are right. I should have posted a "minimum working example" of my problem. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a silly question about an imaginary problem that doesn't not exist in reality. The graphics view will schedule consecutive draws for the items in the order needed to produce the desired result. Now if your code doesn't implement the desired result, that's a whole different subject. There is no concurrency, those are consecutive operations that only take place in the main thread.

If your drawing is very complex, draw using a secondary thread on a `QImage` and use the `QImage` as cache to draw your items in their respective paint functions.

> Now for some reason, I need to show and update both the objects at the
>   same time.

What might that reason be? What does "at the same time" mean? In a single frame? Is a millisecond apart too much to qualify for "at the same time"?